# Add multiple products in session [Django]

Tags: python, django

I would like to add several products to build my basket, but each time I add another product it overwrites the first one, how do I add several products in session?

Views.py

```
def cart_add(request, code):
  dico={"produits":[{'code':'MLO31','nom':'banane sucré','prix':1500}, 
  {'code':'BRAD5','nom':'pomme de terre','prix':1800}]}
  mes_produits=dico['produits']
  session=request.session
  selected_product = next((item for item in mes_produits if item["code"] == code), None)
  if selected_product != None:
    session['nom']=selected_product.get('nom')
    session['prix']=selected_product.get('prix')
  contex={'nom':session['nom'],'prix':session['prix']}

  return render(request, 'cart/cart_detail.html',contex)
```

cart_detail.html

```
   {% for key,value in request.session.items %}
        Nom : {{request.session.nom}}  
        Prix : {{request.session.prix}}<br>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I see that you add `'nom'` and `'prix'` to the `context`, but you never use them. Also you never update `request.session.items`.

Comment: How to implement this

Comment: @Khalifa i have already responded on your other post. Please show the new code you have tried after my comment ?

Comment: @Lucas, yes it's just now I would like to add several products in session, but each time the last one overwrites the last one

Comment: "How to implement this" Add each ordered product to `request.session.items`.

Comment: how to add this to request.session.items : exemple code